# Error in my encryption code in php

Tags: php

Please what could be wrong with my code? The code is meant to encrypt a given string. It does the encryption quite alright but when echoing the encrypted value, it adds numbers to the it. Here is the code:

```php
$keys = "Bb94tU1LSSLgPKNu";
$encrypt = array();

// this contains the key/value pair i used for the encryption
$arrayEncrypt = array("a"=>"g","b"=>"h","c"=>"i","d"=>"j","e"=>"k","f"=>"l","g"=>"m","h"=>"n","i"=>"o","j"=>"p","k"=>"q","l"=>"r", "m"=>"s","n"=>"t","o"=>"u","p"=>"v","q"=>"w","r"=>"x","s"=>"y","t"=>"z","u"=>"a","v"=>"b","w"=>"c","x"=>"d","y"=>"e","z"=>"f","A"=>"G","B"=>"H","C"=>"I","D"=>"J","E"=>"K","F"=>"L","G"=>"M","H"=>"N","I"=>"O","J"=>"P","K"=>"Q","L"=>"R","M"=>"S","N"=>"T","O"=>"U","P"=>"V","Q"=>"W","R"=>"X","S"=>"Y","T"=>"Z","U"=>"A","V"=>"B","W"=>"C","X"=>"D","Y"=>"E","Z"=>"F","0"=>"2","1"=>"4","2"=>"6","3"=>"8","4"=>"0","5"=>"9","6"=>"7","7"=>"5","8"=>"3","9"=>"1");

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($keys); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($keys[$i], $arrayEncrypt)) {  
        foreach ($arrayEncrypt as $key => $letter) {
            if ($keys[$i] == $key) {
                // appends the values of each in $encrypt array
                array_push($encrypt, $letter);
            }
        }
    }
}

$encryptedValue = "";
foreach ($encrypt as $encrypted) {
    $encryptedValue .= $encrypted;
    echo $encryptedValue;
}
```

It prints:

```
H2h210z2A24R2Y2Y2R2m2V2Q2T2a2
```

Instead of:

```
Hh10zA4RYYRmVQTa
```

Comment: This code doesn't even work. Besides the fact you're missing semicolons and doing things like `@$encryptedValue = ...`, when I correct them all it doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Please do not use the snippet feature for non js, css, or html code.

Comment: @Enstage I have pasted the complete code and corrected that line you mentioned. Could you check it now?

Comment: @Daedalus I will try not to next time

Comment: This methodology is to encryption what dice are to random number generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any case, you were over complicating it trying to use the $i instead of just using the name to get the matching value. str_split() to get an array of characters then it's just a matter of $arrayEncrypt[$value]. To undo you can use array_flip().

Made you a nice function to encrypt and decrypt. Enjoy

```
<?php
// 1 to encrypt
// 2 to decrypt
function encdec($do, $keys){
    $arrayEncrypt = array("a"=>"g","b"=>"h","c"=>"i","d"=>"j","e"=>"k","f"=>"l","g"=>"m","h"=>"n","i"=>"o","j"=>"p","k"=>"q","l"=>"r", "m"=>"s","n"=>"t","o"=>"u","p"=>"v","q"=>"w","r"=>"x","s"=>"y","t"=>"z","u"=>"a","v"=>"b","w"=>"c","x"=>"d","y"=>"e","z"=>"f","A"=>"G","B"=>"H","C"=>"I","D"=>"J","E"=>"K","F"=>"L","G"=>"M","H"=>"N","I"=>"O","J"=>"P","K"=>"Q","L"=>"R","M"=>"S","N"=>"T","O"=>"U","P"=>"V","Q"=>"W","R"=>"X","S"=>"Y","T"=>"Z","U"=>"A","V"=>"B","W"=>"C","X"=>"D","Y"=>"E","Z"=>"F","0"=>"2","1"=>"4","2"=>"6","3"=>"8","4"=>"0","5"=>"9","6"=>"7","7"=>"5","8"=>"3","9"=>"1");

    if ($do==2){
        $arrayEncrypt=array_flip($arrayEncrypt);
    }

    $chars = str_split($keys);
    $encryptedValue="";

    foreach($chars as $char=>$value){
        $encryptedValue .= $arrayEncrypt[$value];
    }

    return $encryptedValue;
}

echo "Encrypted key: ".encdec(1,"Bb94tU1LSSLgPKNu")."<br />";
echo "Decrypted key: ".encdec(2,"Hh10zA4RYYRmVQTa")."<br />";

?>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you @Patrick. I'm just a beginner in PHP. I've learnt something new with this answer